# Installing OpenMotif on RHEL 3

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm

Im using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3. I installed openmotif-2.2.2-16.src.rpm by running the bellow command

```
rpm -ivh openmotif-2.2.2-16.src.rpm
```

I got a 100% complete message.But,when i run `rpm -q openmotif`, i get the message "**package openmotif is not installed"**

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You've installed a source RPM, not a binary RPM.

Source RPMs just unpack their source into `/usr/src/redhat/` by default and don't show up in the package database.

You'll need to find (or compile, via `rpmbuild --rebuild <src rpm>`) the right binary RPM for your system.

Answer (score 0):

As James said that you have install openmotif source to change that into binary follow the link

http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-1508

Answer (score 0):

James is correct, but I'd also like to point out that Red Hat Enterprise 3 is EOL and will get no further security updates (http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2010-0817.html).  I'd recommend moving away from RHEL3 to something that's still supported.